# Print file passed in as argument

Tags: python, file

I have a very simple python script that should print the contents of a file that is passed like this: `python script.py stuff.txt`. I don't get any output.

Here is the code:

```
import sys
fname = sys.argv[1]
f = open(fname, 'r')
f.read()
```

From what I have read, this is supposed to work. Why not?

Comment: That code only produces output in the interactive interpreter, which outputs the result of each expression it evaluates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You read the file, but you don't do anything with the data.

```
print(f.read())
```

Or, for better style:

```
import sys
fname = sys.argv[1]
with open(fname, 'r') as f:
    print(f.read())
```

This is the recommended way to use files. It guarantees the file is closed when you exit the `with` block. Does not really matter for your small script, but it's a good habit to take.

Comment: Thanks! I tried print f.read(). What is the difference? Does enclosing the content in () mean to run that rather than show it?

Comment: Depends. In python2, `print f.read()` should work. In python3, it should raise a syntax error. But in both versions, if you type `print f.read()` in the debugger it should work, because the debugger will take the `print` for itself, just run `f.read()` then display the result. **However** in all cases, once you have run `f.read()` once on a file, all subsequent `f.read()` will be empty _(unless the file has grown)_. That's because the file descriptor is not “rewinded” between calls. You may rewind it using `f.seek(0)`.